# get each date for given year in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, calendar

we want to get each date of the moth for given year. do we have any such query in mysql to get day and date?

for example: for 2017 we want to get table like below

```
 date  
 ----------
 01-01-2017
 02-01-2017
 03-01-2017
 .
 .
 .
 31-12-2017
```

Comment: Not really.  You can list the values in a subquery, however.

Comment: we did not get it clearly. Can you explain us in brief ?

Comment: You may write a procedure where you fix `current_date` and a variable, print `subdate(current_date, interval -1 day) ` and increment the variable till it reaches the end of the year.

Comment: Ya. I saw that somewhere. will let you know that after working on it. thanks :)